# Can mobify.js be used to create retina friendly images?

Tags: retina, mobify, mobify-js

Can mobify.js be used to create retina friendly images? Trying to find more info on making images that have already been created retina friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Mobify.js is a library that can be used to resize a given image for all kinds of devices. The ideal workflow using Mobify.js is that you would upload retina images, and you let Mobify.js take care of resizing them down for different sized devices. However, if your images are low resolution, Mobify.js cannot make them retina. It is up to you to ensure that you have the best quality images uploaded, and Mobify.js will take care of reducing their size for different devices.

Feel free to read more about it here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/24/automate-your-responsive-images-with-mobify-js/